# Creating and populating inset maps for densely-labelled areas using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I would like to know if it is possible to automate the example in the picture below, unlike the picture below i'm using vector data.

I would like for a fixed scale generate map, but when labels are too dense, we could have some little maps (inset maps) on the side of the Main map.

i have found some [tips using arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000031000000).

but the **problem is how to detect densely labelled areas**

[image]

Comment: this question seem to tackle the same problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29637/how-to-produce-a-better-inset-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to automate would be Data Driven Pages or to use ArcPy mapping module:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Exporting_Data_Driven_Pages/00sm00000008000000/

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/