# Visual connection between two linked frames in QGis Print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am still a beginner.

I created a printing preview in Print composer, with a general map on the background and several small frames on top, containing zoomed-in portions of the general map.

With the "Overviews" tab, in the "Item properties", I linked the small frames to the relative area in the general map, which now is also surrounded by a frame. I would now like to know if there is a way to create a visual connection between these two frames (e.g. an arrow connecting the frame on the general map to the small frame with the zoomed-in portion) without having to draw it manually. I can not find a function for that.

Comment: i think a screenshot of a map with the effect you're trying to achieve might help. Do you mean something [like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29637/55203), but in QGIS?

Comment: Exactly, something which visually connects the small frame to the background map, like in the link you posted. Thank you. I will try to get a screenshot if it's needed. I am not in front of my laptop at the moment.